# Using Scala's groupBy with "eligible deviation"

Tags: scala

I have:

```
val a = List((1.1, 2), (1.2, 3), (3.1, 4), (2.9, 5))
```

I want to group this list with "eligible deviation", or in other words: group every double with doubles that are bigger/smaller than itself.

The result I want (Let's say that the eligible deviation here is 0.2):

```
Map((1.1, 1.2) -> List((1.1, 2),(1.2, 3)), (3.1, 2.9) -> List((3.1, 4), (2.9, 5)))
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What if you have `1.1, 1.2, 1.3, ... , 100.1, 100.2`? How will this be grouped, one group?

Comment: What is the expected output for this input: `List((1.1, 2), (1.1, 3), (1.1, 4), (2.9, 5))`?

Comment: jwvh : a group of 3 (1.1s) and a group of one (2.9)

Comment: Psidom: Theoretically yes. But the example Psidom mentioned is not plausible in my collection.

Comment: How about `1.1, 1.2, 10.1, 10.2, 1.3, 1.2` then? How many groups should this situation have?

Comment: 2 groups: `(1.1, 1.2, 1.3) (10.1, 10.2)` , I omitted the 2nd `1.2` because all the values are unique in my collection.

Comment: No, every data collection that contain groups as mentioned above is fine.

Comment: But what you are showing is a Map, I think a List of lists might be easier.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want:

```
// sort the list by the first element in each tuple
val sort_a = a.sortBy(_._1)

// calculate the difference of consecutive tuples by the first element
val diff = sort_a.scanLeft((0.0, 0.0))((x,y) => (y._1 - x._2, y._1)).tail

// create a group variable based on the difference and tolerance
val g = diff.scanLeft(0)((x, y) => if(y._1 < 0.201) x else x + 1).tail
// g: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 2, 2)

// zip the list and the group variable and split the list up by the group variable
sort_a.zip(g).groupBy(_._2).mapValues(_.map(_._1))
// res62: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[(Double, Int)]] = 
// Map(2 -> List((2.9,5), (3.1,4)), 1 -> List((1.1,2), (1.2,3)))
```

Comment: I like this. Looks so clean. I think performance wise, what I did below with the recursive implementation may give better byte-code, but it looks so complicated (even though it really wasn't that hard to code) ...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a (tail)recursive implementation. The main difference with using `scan` and the Collections API is that the compiler de-sugar this to a while-loop which typically runs pretty fast.

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def grouper(seq: List[(Double,Int)], delta: Double): Map[List[Double], List[(Double,Int)]] = {
 @tailrec def loop(rest: List[(Double,Int)], last: Double, curGroup: List[(Double,Int)], allGroups: List[List[(Double,Int)]]): List[List[(Double,Int)]] = {
    rest match {
       case h::t  if Math.abs( h._1 - last ) <= delta => loop(t, h._1, h :: curGroup, allGroups)
       case h::t =>  loop(t, h._1, h :: Nil, if(curGroup.nonEmpty) curGroup :: allGroups else allGroups)
       case _ => if(curGroup.nonEmpty) curGroup :: allGroups else allGroups
    }
 }
 val list = loop(seq, Double.NegativeInfinity, List.empty, List.empty)
 list.map(x => (x.map(_._1), x)).toMap
```

}

Using it:

```
> grouper(List((1.1, 2), (1.2, 3), (1.3, 4), (2.9, 5)), 0.2)
res1: Map[List[Double], List[(Double, Int)]] = Map(List(2.9) -> List((2.9, 5)), List(1.3, 1.2, 1.1) -> List((1.3, 4), (1.2, 3), (1.1, 2)))
```